# Swig - why we need to declare functions twice?

Tags: java, c, swig

I want to use swig in order to call C functions from Java.
I read:
[SWIG Tutorial](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html)

And the web contains the interface file example:

```
/* example.i */
 %module example
 %{
 /* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
 extern double My_variable;
 extern int fact(int n);
 extern int my_mod(int x, int y);
 extern char *get_time();
 %}

 extern double My_variable;
 extern int fact(int n);
 extern int my_mod(int x, int y);
 extern char *get_time();
```

Why there are duplicates at the functions declarations ?
(for example "extern int fact(int n);" declared in {% %} and in the bottom  of the file ?

Comment: Maybe it's just an example where function declarations can appear.

Comment: I saw it in other examples without explanations ...

Comment: Because you can either include a header file, or declare your functions prototypes.

Comment: so instead of write the declarations of the 4 functions, I can write the declaration of the .h file ?

Comment: Note that you can use the syntax `%inline %{ ... %}` to avoid this duplication. See the SWIG docs [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nn43)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stuff inside the %{ %} block is copied exactly into the the generated c file (example_wrap.c) to be used as a forward prototype. The stuff outside the block is used to generate the functions inside the generated .c file.

A better example would have assumed you already had a header file like example.h with something like this:

```
extern void functionIwantToCallFromJava(int);
extern crazyType *functionIDoNotCareAbout(anotherCrazyType *);
```

so inside example.i you have

```
%{ 
#include "example.h"
%}
extern void functionIwantToCallFromJava(int);
```

Now the generated file will have #include "example.h" near the beginning which it needs so that functionIwantToCallFromJava is properly prototyped, 
but SWIG doesn't have to generate a lot of code to implement functionIDoNotCareAbout even though it is defined in the same header file.